# Configuration.GetValue<T> returning null but Bind works

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I'm having a problem getting data from my `appsettings.json`.
The file looks like:

```
  "Integrations": {
    "System01": {
      "Host": "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616)?transport.timeout=2000",
      "User": "admin",
      "Password": "admin"
    },
    "System02": {
      "Host": "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616)?transport.timeout=2000",
      "User": "admin",
      "Password": "admin"
    },
  }
```

I have the following DTO:

```
public class IntegrationsConfigurationDto
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to read it like:

```
var config = _configuration.GetValue<IntegrationsConfigurationDto>("Integrations:System01");
```

I get `null`. But if I do:

```
var config = new IntegrationsConfigurationDto();
_config.Bind("Integrations:System01", config);
```

I get the values correctly in my `config` variable.

Why does that happen? How can I use `GetValue<T>` in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you use the 2nd approach?

Comment: I can. Just want to know why the first one doesn't work and if there's something I could do for it to work.

Comment: I think GetValue is used for a single value, not for a section.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`GetValue` only works for simple values, such as `string`, `int`, etc - it doesn't traverse the hierarchy of nested configuration.

Reference: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#getvalue)

> `ConfigurationBinder.GetValue<T>` extracts a value from configuration with a specified key and converts it to the specified type. An overload permits you to provide a default value if the key isn't found.

Instead of using `Bind`, use the following to avoid having to create your own instance of `IntegrationsConfigurationDto`:

```
var config = _configuration.GetSection("Integrations:System01")
    .Get<IntegrationsConfigurationDto>();
```

Reference: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-an-object-graph)

> `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` binds and returns the specified type. `Get<T>` is more convenient than using `Bind`.