# How to get an appSetting after configuration (ASP.NET web API DI)

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have registered an appSetting :
`RegisterSettings<CommonSettings>(sc, "common")`
This method itself returns the settings instance but how can I get it
in a separate class / method in the start-up process
either using the `IConfiguration` or `IServiceCollection` reference?

I tried with `_config.GetValue<CommonSettings>("common")` but this returned `null`.

Thanks!

Comment: `GetValue` doesn't work with complex types, so [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022143/configuration-getvaluet-returning-null-but-bind-works/56022347#56022347) might help.

Comment: I found that this worked `var commonSettings = _config.GetSection("common").Get<CommonSettings>();`